# Firebase Function onWrite returns undefined event.data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

My firebase function is triggering onWrite but its event has no data.

My Function index file

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
var firestore = admin.firestore();
var logInLogOutListner = require('./logInLogOutListner');



exports.listenForLogInLogOut = database.ref('/message')
    .onWrite((event,context) => {

     console.log("data:"+event.data+"event:"+event);

      if (!event.data.exists()) {
        return;
      }

        logInLogOutListner.listenForLogInLogOut(firestore, event.data);

return null;

 });
```

Firebase functions logs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWj45.png)

Comment: Have a look at this documentation item about the new version of Cloud Functions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database. You are probably using a CF version above 1.0.0 but call it with the old syntax.

Comment: It looks like you're using both Realtime Database and Firestore at the same time. Also, I don't think this code would actually run, because you're not declaring your function correctly.  Are you sure this is the exact code?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec thanks , I was struggling for hours.

Comment: @Right2Trick Good to know. However I would recommend you follow Doug's advice about the fact that your code is not 100% correct. You should watch Doug's videos about this subject: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=24s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=652XeeKNHSk. (Without any sycophancy! :-)